# How to create SQL constraint on primary key to make sure it could only be referenced once?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do I add constraint to guard that a primary key could only be referenced once?(It could be referenced in two tables)
Each reference should have a unique value out of the primary key.

```
Table A
----------------------
id            
1             
2
3
4             

Table B
----------------------
id            a_id (foreign key to table A.id)
1             2
2             3


Table C
----------------------
id            a_id (foreign key to table A.id)
1             1
```

I want something to happen to give error when try to insert a_id = 2 into table C as its used in table B already.

Comment: Can you add some detail about your schema so we can see how your tables are setup and how you want them to relate to each other, your question is a little unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do requires another table `D`, that will help unify the references to `A`.
Table `D` will contain its own  primary key ( `Id` ), a reference to table `A` with a `UNIQUE` constraint on it (call it `AId` ), and a third column (called `"RowType"`) to indicate to which of the child tables (`B` or `C`) the row corresponds. You can make this column to be of type int, and assign value `"0"` for `B` and `"1"` for `C`, for example.

Then in table `B` you add a foreign key to `D.Id`, AND another column `"BRowType"` as  foreign key to `D.RowType`; then you define a constraint on this column, so it can only have the value `'0'` ( or whatever value you have decided to correspond to this table).
For table `C` your constraint will limit the values to `'1'`.

Or course, in order to insert a record into `B` or `C` you first need to create a record in `D`. But once you have a record in `B` that references a record in `D`, which in turn links to a record in `A`, you will no longer be able to create a record in `C` for the same line in `A` - because of the `UNIQUE` constraint on `D.AId` AND the constraint on `C.BRowType`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an INSERT, UPDATE trigger on each of the child tables to ensure that the PK of the parent table that is about to be inserted or updated does not already exist in the other child table.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, it sounds like you need to add a unique constraint on the column of each table that references your primary key.

For example:

```
Table A
----------------------
id (primary key)
1
2
3

Table B
----------------------
id            a_id (foreign key to table A.id)
1             2
2             3
```

Set the a_id column to be UNIQUE and that way you can ensure that the primary key from Table A is not used twice. You would do that in each table which references A.id

Comment: Yes, I understand that but my question is if we have a Table C that references Table A as well, how to make sure the uniqueness between a_id in both table B and table C?(So it would only appear once)

Comment: Got it, that makes sense now, yea I would think that using triggers as @rd_nielsen suggests is probably the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using triggers, you could create a table X with id and a unique constraint on it. 
In each transaction in which you insert a record into B or C you have to insert into X as well. Both insertions will only be possible if not yet in the other table.

Comment: This is basicly the solution using table D without RowType and it's own primary key. Which I do not understand why they should be necessary. The Unique-Constraint on the id should be enough. 2 inserts are necessary anyway. You have to make sure, that both inserts are in one transaction!!